# Allow user to use OR in aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting elastic search to produce the facets/aggregations I want do display to my users.

**TLTR**

I wan't the facets to behave the facets on this site: 
https://mad.coop.dk/frugt-og-groent#!/frugt-og-baer

---

Imagine a search page where we are displaying cars for sale. A car is modeled like this:

**Car**

```
{
    "brand": "Ford",
    "color": "Blue"
}
```

**INDEXING**

Adding 4 cars to the index

```
POST /agg_analysis/data/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "brand" : "Ford", "color":"Blue" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "brand" : "Ford", "color":"Red" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "brand" : "Toyota", "color":"Blue" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "brand" : "Toyota", "color":"Yellow" }
```

**INITIAL FACETS**

On the left side of the page we allow the users to filter the cars

[image]

**INITIAL QUERY**

The aggregation is straight forward

```
GET /agg_analysis/data/_search
{

  "aggs": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**USE CASE 1: FIND ME A BLUE CAR**

The user click the color: blue facet and the facets and cars are updated accordingly

[image]

```
GET /agg_analysis/data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "color": {
        "value": "blue"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All is fine and user is happy

**USE CASE 2: FIND ME A BLUE OR RED CAR**

This is where the problems begins. When the user clicked the blue checkbox the red checkbox disappeared.

So what I want is that all the facets are updated - except the one the user clicks in.

**USE CASE 3: FIND ME A BLUE OR RED CAR, AND IT SHOULD BE A FORD**

This is kinda the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to change your query to use `post_filter` instead of `query`, i.e. let the aggregations be computed on the full set of the documents, and only then filter the resulting documents using `post_filter`. Using `query`, the documents are filtered **prior** to running aggregations, hence why you don't see all facets anymore.

```
GET /agg_analysis/data/_search
{
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "color": {
        "value": "blue"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "brand": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "color": {
            "value": "blue"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "brand"
        }
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You also see that the `brand` aggregation is filtered to only show brands with `blue` colors.